# web app with MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean

I have to deploy a login page with profile with node js, mongodb and angularjs. Can you suggest me an example of MEAN in mongoDB and not in mongoose? I have to store credentials user's with mongodb and I have to send user's data to the client, not in json.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose is a interface to connect to mongo databases in NodeJs environment. To perform login and send data to client, you can follow these steps:

1. Send a login request to server.
2. Verify the user credentials and send a token back to user for proceed with further requests for client data. For this, you can use JWT.
3. Put an interceptor in angularjs which will automatically associate the token in header with each request corresponds to valid user.
4. At server end, you can check whether requests consist of token or not. If not, you can send unauthorized in response (401).